# Canvas distorts drawing. How do I get the scale factor between the set size and the styled size?

Tags: css, html, canvas, distortion

I have this canvas:

```
<canvas id="game" width="280" height="280"></canvas>
```

The css styles the canvas via:

```
canvas
{
    width: inherit;
    height: 280px;
}
```

**As the width can change, the canvas distorts the drawing. I need to know how to compensate for this.** Anyone who can help me?

Comment: The canvas must always be a square, and fit the element containing it?

Comment: No, the canvas can change in size, both height as width. (Depending on device, browser size, etc...) But I want an absolute, undistorted context.

Comment: I think it depends on what type of application you have. What are you drawing?

Comment: Are you using relative values? I.E. percentage of canvas size?

Comment: No, absolute figures. px only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3770/discussion-between-melight-and-kriem)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same problem that the Mozilla Bespin team ran into. (back when they were using Canvas, before it merged with Ace)

**Don't give the Canvas any CSS width/height rules.** Doing so usually ends up as a pain. Put the Canvas in a Div that only has a single thing in it (the canvas itself)

As the canvas-parent div changes size, change the size of the canvas (canvas.width and canvas.height) to match the size of the div.

Since most browsers do not fire an event when a div changes size, you'll simply have to check, say, every half second with a timer to see if the div has changed size. If it has, then you resize the canvas accordingly.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, CSS `width` and `height` attributes affect the scaling of the canvas element, while object-level `width` and `height` declarations actually set the dimensions of the canvas. Also, since the canvas will be resized, a function will need to be hooked into the resize event so that the old data can be carried over. Resizing a canvas clears its contents. A simple `getImageData()` before the resize and then `putImageData()` after the resize will take care of this.

Comment: I looks like changing the size of the canvas is the only controllable solution. It's fixed now, but what a pain in the behind.