# Div with overflow:hidden, border-radius and canvas as child. Overflow buggy depending on size canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, overflow, css

I had a major headbreaker today.The "bug" seems to depend on the size of the canvas inside the rounded div.  Who can explain this fiddle behaviour and has a solution for this "bug" in firefox 16.0.2./chrome Check the fiddle with FF, IE and chrome...

```
overflow not hidden in firefox 16
<div class="round"  >
<canvas  width="300px" height="300px">
    Your browser needs canvas support</canvas>
</div>
overflow hidden in firefox 16
<div class="round"  >
<canvas  width="12000px" height="7200px">
    Your browser needs canvas support</canvas>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/m3jtc/31/)

Comment: it seems that the bug is only depended on the width of the canvas. The bug is solved when the canvas width = or > 8193px. This may depend on screen resolution (my screen width is 1366 pixels)... didn't do a test on other srceen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a bug and I didn't find any other solution then setting a huge width for the canvas element, there is no correct answer for this question at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about canvas, but your inline `width="300px" height="300px"` struck me as incorrect.  If you defer these to a stylesheet, or an inline `style` attribute, you should get the result you intend:

```
<canvas style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
```

Comment: this is not true. Check this fiddle for proof http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/m3jtc/34/ it really depends from the width of the canvas.

Comment: well, it isn't on my win 7 box with firefox 16.0.2 (screen res. 1366 x 768). It solved the problem for Chrome though! What platform are you on and what version of firefox?

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong thing to do. The canvas element is supposed to be styled with the width and height attribute and NOT with CSS attributes. CSS scales the canvas, it does not resize it. See for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545863/canvas-distorts-drawing-how-do-i-get-the-scale-factor-between-the-set-size-and/7547670#7547670

Comment: yes indeed, css does the scaling. though, it can be a solution for some cases. The only workaround that I know of is setting the width (not css) of the canvas at >8193px. Can someone confirm this and mention OS, browser version and screen resolution.